# Незнакомая последняя сессия на сервере

Tags: linux, debian, ssh, tor

"Мой кент" поднял tor exit node на своём сервере, при логине сервера по shh выдаёт `Last login: Thu Oct 22 17:54:00 2020 from "неизвестный мне ip"`
При переходе по этому ip открывается неизвестная тор нода
Это специфика работы тор ноды или на сервер логинился злоумышленник?

Answer (score 0):

логин сервера, это последний IP с которого был удачный логин в вашу систему.

p.s.
может это "ваш кент" логинится в ваш сервер через ТОР ?